# Accessing websites in a dropdown list

Tags: web-scraping, drop-down-menu, automation, data-collection

I'm trying to build a web scraper that visits school district websites and retrieves the names and websites of the schools. I'm using https://www.dallasisd.org/ to test the code below.

I'm currently stuck on how to 1) only access the dropdown list of 'Schools' and 2) retrieve the links in the `<li>` tags in the same dropdown.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.request
import requests
import re
import xlwt
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy
import os.path

hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' }
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.dallasisd.org/'
browser.get(url)
html_source = browser.page_source
browser.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "lxml")
for name_list in soup.find_all(class_ ='sw-dropdown-list'):
    print(name_list.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown lists of elementary schools are contained in the <div id="cs-elementary-schools-panel" [...]> which you could access prior to finding all  and obtain the links:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://www.dallasisd.org/'

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
dropdown = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': "cs-elementary-schools-panel"})

for link in dropdown.find_all('li', attrs={'class': "cs-panel-item"}):
   print("Url: https://www.dallasisd.org" + link.find('a')['href'])
```

You can easily extend this code to the Middle and High schools